# Business Statistics

Tags: standard-deviation

a teacher gives a 15 item science test. for each item, a student receives one point for a correct answer; 0 points for no answer; and loses one point for an incorrect answer. total test scores could range from +15 points to -15 points. the teacher computes the standard deviation for the class to be -2.30. What do we know

Comment: What exactly are you asking for with "What do we know"?

Comment: Hi Shimea, and welcome to CV. Your question needs to be carefully edited before it can reasonably be answered - it is confusing or mistaken on several grounds, a number of them already expressed here. Could you please take a look through the [help on asking questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [discussion of how to ask a good question](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated) from our meta site, and after pondering what it is you need to know, edit your question taking account of the comments and guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

We know a few things:

1. This looks a lot like homework and therefore you should include the "Self Study" tag.
2. You need to read more of your textbook and pay better attention in class, this should be an easy answer.
3. The teacher either made a calculation mistake, is really bad at math, or is using a very different definition of standard deviation from the rest of us (or made the mistake of thinking that a spreadsheet program is a reasonable tool for computing statistics).
4. The teacher is really strict about penalizing for guessing, the usual penalties work out that the expected value for guessing is the same as for leaving the answer blank.

Comment: Because I know you have no tendency to make *ad hominem* arguments or characterizations, I must presume these rather severe-sounding comments, especially #2 and #3, are responses to the fact that the "standard deviation" quoted in the question is negative.

Comment: @whuber, I will admit 2 and 3 are based on the assumption that 1 is true, and also that the parenthetical about spreadsheets is an opinion (but does "to the person" in Latin apply to computer programs, but then I would be surprised if there was a Latin word/phrase for computer program).  The fact that the standard definition of SD does not allow a negative number is fact rather than opinion.  I thought 3 would be helpful (assuming 1) pointing the user in the direction of math errors.